# proguard : Got "encrypted ZIP entry not supported " error when building from build.xml

Tags: proguard

Am using Proguard to make my classes non-decompilable. I have added an Ant task in my build.xml file. Below is the snippet.

```
<target name="obfuscate">
 <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="${lib.dir}/proguard.jar" />
    <proguard>
           <injar file="${build.dir}/api.jar" />
       <outjar file="${build.dir}/finalApi.jar" />
       <libraryjar refid="standard-classpath" />
      <keepdirectory name="${src.class.dir}/config.zip" />
        </proguard>
</target>
```

I have a config zip file in my jar which is encrypted as it contains certificates, which i do not want the user to see. When i using progaurd to create the new jar, i am getting the below error.
\build.xml:100: Can't read [\classes] (**encrypted ZIP entry not supported**)

Please let me know how can i include this file in the new jar created through progaurd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard reads all input directories and archives (also nested ones) in order to process them. It will fail on encrypted entries. You could add such entries after ProGuard has run in the build process, or you could try using a different extension for encrypted zip files.